# Are maledictions curses?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, curses

RE: Maledictor class

They sure SEEM like curses, but does Remove Curse work on Maledictions? Can I use Harrowed Strike on someone affected by a Malediction?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. By *maledictor* is this question asking about the third-party base class [malefactor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/) and that class's spell-like ability [maledictions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/#TOC-Malediction-Sp-)? Enjoy your stay and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

### [Malefactor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/)

> [Maledictions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/#TOC-Malediction-Sp-)
>
> [Harrowing Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/#TOC-Harrowing-Strike-Su-)

If you are speaking of the Malefactor Class from TPK games, it would see that **no, Maledictions are not Curse effects by RAW** because none of the Maledictions and the Class Feature itself doesn't say it is, so its not.

However, **they seem to be intended to be Curse effects** based on other class feature(s) and the Malefactor's bonuses that only apply to Cursed targets. Because it's third party content, this was likely an oversight caused by them not using the same syntax as Paizo (or Wizards of the Coast). Speak with your GM to see if they'll homerule that a Malediction effect is also a Curse effect.